# How to search for Tags that matches a particular pattern using JGit

Tags: git, github, egit, jgit

I want to list down tags from Git repository that matches a particular pattern. I found a way to do it in Git Bash

```
$ git tag -l "proj1/1.1*"
```

which will return me only

```
proj1/1.1
proj1/1.1.1
proj1/1.1.2
```

But i dont know how to do the same using jgit.
I have tried the below code to retrieve tags from repository

```
FileRepositoryBuilder repositoryBuilder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
repositoryBuilder.addCeilingDirectory(new File("D:\\Repo"));
repositoryBuilder.findGitDir(new File("D:\\Repo\\.git"));
Repository repo = repositoryBuilder.build();

List<String> tagList = new ArrayList<String>();
Map<String, Ref> tags = repo.getTags();
for (Map.Entry<String, Ref> entry : tags.entrySet()) {
      tagList.add(entry.getKey());
}
```

The above code is returning me all tags corresponding to that repository like below

```
proj1/1.1
proj1/1.1.1
proj1/1.1.2
proj2/2.1
proj3/3.1
```

I don't know how to filter tags using JGit. Can anyone help me on this

Comment: Why do you need JGit to filter the tags? You could filter tags after having obtained them from `Repository::getTags`.

Comment: But i am having huge Tag list so i am just worried it will affect the performance.

Comment: Are you worried about the performance or do you know that the huge tag list will be a performance issue? Unless the latter is the case, I'd suggest to go with what's there and address the performance issue when you have a good understanding of what exactly performs bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
repo.getRefDatabase().getRefsByPrefix("refs/tags/proj1/1.1")
```

JGit 5.9.0.202009080501-r.